# Are we supposed to delete migration snapshot when migrating db to .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.1

If we have existing database migrations and a snapshot file in our .NET Core 1 project, are we supposed to delete the snapshot in .Net Core 2 before we do a new migration?

EDIT:

I noticed the snapshot file with the new migration has a

`.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.0.0-rtm-26452")`
Where as my previous migrations were:

`.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.1.2")`

It ef core just skipping my old migration files because of the different versions? Because I investigated my new migration file with all previous migrations and it looks like it has no knowledge of those previous ones.

Comment: what are the ef core versions?

Comment: if you have an existing database, recreating a new migration means you wouldn't be able to update your existing db form its current stage

Comment: @NevilleNazerane My previous one was ef core 1.1.2 and now I am on 2.0. I dont quite follow you(Sorry I'm new to sql/.net). But are you saying that I won't be able to use my data from ef core 1.1.2 in my ported app?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to delete anything as you to the migration, as the framework is smart enough to know what you are doing. Just make sure that when you upgrade your project that you do the following.

1. Update all package references to the new 2.x versions
2. Update all tooling references to the new 2.x versions

If you do this, you should be able to add a new migration without any issues after updating your project.

Comment: If running `dotnet ef database update` fails on the very first migration file(generated during version 1) what would that generally mean? I also wiped my database to test what would happen in a new environment and it seems to be failing as well.

Comment: There should be a message about why it failed, can you share that?

Comment: Yeah I'm now getting a : "Cannot drop the index 'AspNetUsers.UserNameIndex', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I also see the userNameIndex this time around. It used to not exist before, but now it does exist.

I also made a post here if you need a additional info:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11763